# Remove auto select of radio button in ng-repeat Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I am dynamically populating the radio button using a json. And using ng-repeat to display it. My issue is that the last radio button gets picked by default which I don't want. I don't see any reason for it to be selected.

```
 <div ng-repeat="bankAccount in availableBankAccounts">
            <div class="account-list grey-bottom-border">
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <label class="radio col-xs-12 spacer-top-sm option-label">
                  <input type="radio" name="radio2" ng-model="updateDD.bankAccountId" ng-value="updateDD.bankAccountId" ng-click="selectedReason(bankAccount)" required="" class="ng-untouched ng-dirty ng-valid ng-valid-required">
                  <span class="control-indicator control-indicator-lg hand-cursor"></span>
                  <span>Account ending in *{{bankAccount.depositAccountNumber|last4Digits}}</span>
                </label>
                <!-- <p>Account ending in *7890</p> -->
              </div>

            </div>
            </div>
```

Js file:

```
$scope.updateDD.bankAccountId=$scope.radio7;
if($scope.availableBankAccounts.length>1)
            {
            $scope.createJson();
            }
```

Any help indicating what is making last radio button select by default will be helpful.

Comment: Tried. No change in the output

Answer (score 0):

Try $scope.availableBankAccounts.length>=1

Should work

Comment: For equal to one there is another condition `$scope.radio7=$scope.availableBankAccounts[0].id;`

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the same value to  `ng-model`, where you want to see the selected value and `ng-value`, which you want to use for value.

Instead of

```
ng-model="updateDD.bankAccountId" ng-value="updateDD.bankAccountId"
```

you should do something like

```
ng-model="updateDD.bankAccountId" ng-value="bankAccount.Id"
```

Comment: Tried this also nothing changed

Comment: you have to make sure that `updateDD.bankAccountId` has no value then. in the code you shared `$scope.updateDD.bankAccountId=$scope.radio7;` will assign it some value, i guess exactly the last one's equal